# How do I get a Sony VAIO vgn-cr120e webcam working?

Tags: 11.10, webcam, vaio, sony, cheese

I have a Sony Vaio VGN-CR120E with Ubuntu 11.10.  My webcam will not work with skype or cheese.  It simply says "No Device Found".  Can somebody please help me fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry that I cannot provide an exact answer, but whenever I have a problem with Sony Vaio's I always hit up [this Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/vaio-f11-linux/issues/list) page.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: fix found at http://askubuntu.com/questions/294029/nearly-a-question-sony-vaio-webcam-12-04