# Sony Vaio WebCam shows the error "No WebCam Detected"

Tags: 12.04, webcam, vaio, sony

The initial problem.
**Errors on boot up pointing to USB2 the Sony Vaio webcam.**

Errors after loading Ubuntu 12.04
**No WebCam detected.**

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix found at https://bitbucket.org/ahixon/r5u87x

Enter the code, 1 command at a time, into a terminal window.

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev libusb-dev build-essential gcc automake mercurial
hg clone http://bitbucket.org/ahixon/r5u87x/
cd r5u87x
make
sudo make install
sudo r5u87x-loader --reload
```

The loader will automatically be run on boot when it detects your webcam.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>moved OP's answer here that was originally in their question</sub>

The fix found at https://bitbucket.org/ahixon/r5u87x

Enter the code, 1 command at a time, into a terminal window.

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev libusb-dev build-essential gcc automake mercurial
hg clone http://bitbucket.org/ahixon/r5u87x/
cd r5u87x
make
sudo make install
sudo r5u87x-loader --reload
```

The loader will automatically be run on boot when it detects your webcam.