# VAIO webcam r5u87x

Tags: webcam

I have issues with a Sony Vaio webcam.And yes I tried the whole r5u87x fix.

Apparently the last step fails in a

```
Error: Failed to find any supported webcams.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Backinfo:

```
lsusb outputs shows no signs of an intergrated camera
/dev has no video0
```

[link for fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294029/nearly-a-question-sony-vaio-webcam-12-04?rq=1)

Also I am finding it quite hard to get any info on what type of camera chipset is being used.

It's a Vaio PCG-71C12L

Comment: What fix? Where's the link? And you sure you have the camera?

Comment: @Braiam Webcam is integrated and was working before Linux switch